# Can we get sample from avplayer or mpmovieplayer? OR can we pass avplayer and MpmoviePlayer to audio unit?

Tags: objective-c

Can we get sample from avplayer or mpmovieplayer? OR can we pass avplayer and MpmoviePlayer to audio unit?
I iam using m3u8 file with avplayer and i am not able to get sample from it . Or IS any other  way by which we can get the sample from m3u8 . i am using avplayer because in core audio m3u8 file is not supported so this is only alternative.